# C# .Net WinForms app: anonymous collection- how to caste return type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, casting, anonymous-types

Seems like this is a recorring problem for me.  I am again having a problem with casting type when I use an anonymous collection. My query from the XML file returns a collection of string values.  I am trying to return these values from my data access layer to my business logic layer.  Thanks in advance.

```
    public string[] getCustDetails(string customerId)
    {
        //Pulls customer information for selected customer
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
        var custRecord = from account in doc.Descendants("acct")
                         let acct = account.Element("acct")
                         where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                         select new
                         {
                             Fname = (string)account.Attribute("fname").Value,
                             Lname = (string)account.Attribute("lname").Value,
                             Ssn = (string)account.Attribute("ssn").Value,
                             Dob = (string)account.Attribute("dob").Value,
                             Custid = (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value
                         };
return ?????

    }
```

Comment: What would this return array look like?  It's not clear to me how you are planning on representing your anonymous composite object as a string array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use anonymous types are either parameters to a method or a return type.

I suggest creating a simple class with the properties you need and use that instead of an anonymous type.

```
public class AccountDetails
{
  public string FName { get; set; }
  public string LName { get; set; }
  public string Ssn { get; set; }
  public string Dob { get; set; }
  public string Custid { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<AccountDetails> getCustDetails(string customerId)
{
    //Pulls customer information for selected customer
    var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
    var custRecords = from account in doc.Descendants("acct")
                     let acct = account.Element("acct")
                     where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                     select new AccountDetails
                     {
                         Fname = (string)account.Attribute("fname").Value,
                         Lname = (string)account.Attribute("lname").Value,
                         Ssn = (string)account.Attribute("ssn").Value,
                         Dob = (string)account.Attribute("dob").Value,
                         Custid = (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value
                     };

    return custRecords;
}
```

Comment: How do I type the collection that is being returned to my business logic layeer(DLGetCustomers obj = new DLGetCustomers();)??  Some collection type should equal:  obj.GetCustDetails

Comment: Sorry, I'm really struggling with these generic collections.

Comment: @Susan - Seeing as I don't know what type you are expecting in return, I can't really help. You can use a list of the suggested `AccountDetails` class.

Answer (score 1):

create new class for the requirement and return it as a list...

```
    public MyClass[] getCustDetails(string customerId)
    {
        //Pulls customer information for selected customer
        var doc = XDocument.Load("Portfolio.xml");
        var custRecord = (from account in doc.Descendants("acct")
                         let acct = account.Element("acct")
                         where (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value == customerId
                         select new MyClass
                         {
                             Fname = (string)account.Attribute("fname").Value,
                             Lname = (string)account.Attribute("lname").Value,
                             Ssn = (string)account.Attribute("ssn").Value,
                             Dob = (string)account.Attribute("dob").Value,
                             Custid = (string)account.Attribute("custid").Value
                         }).ToArray();
   return custRecord;

    }
```

define your class as

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Fname  { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Ssn { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public string Custid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new class containing the following properties.

```
 string Fname
 string Lname
 string Ssn
 string Dob
 string Custid
```

Then return this type from your getCustDetails() method